# Using VirtualPathProvider to load ASP.NET MVC views from DLLs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, virtualpathprovider

Based on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-seperate-assemblies-in-aspnet-mvc) and using code found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx) I'm trying to load views that are embedded resources in a separate DLL project, and the original question's author says he has had success doing this - but I can't get it to work as it seems the MVC view engine is intercepting the request and still looking at the file system for the view. Exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The view 'Index' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/admin/Index.aspx
~/Views/admin/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/App/Views/admin/Index.aspx
~/App/Views/admin/Index.ascx
~/App/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/App/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
```

I am using a `CustomViewEngine`, like Rob Connery's /App structure one as follows:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
    {
         public CustomViewEngine()
         {
             MasterLocationFormats = new[] { 
                "~/App/Views/{1}/{0}.master", 
                "~/App/Views/Shared/{0}.master" 
                };

             ViewLocationFormats = new[] { 
                "~/App/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx", 
                "~/App/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx", 
                "~/App/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx", 
                "~/App/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx" 
                };

             PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;
         }
    }
```

Here are my routes:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new {controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = "Default"});
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "Page/{id}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = "" });
    routes.MapRoute("Plugins", "plugin/{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "", action = "Index", id = "" });
    routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "ResourceNotFound404" });
```

In my [`AssemblyResourceProvider`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx) I'm checking to see if the path starts `~/plugin/` and then using the dll filename convention `plugin.{controller}.dll`

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** By the time the routed request for say `http://localhost/plugin/admin` is getting to the VirtualFileProvider it doesn't have any View attached at the end. So in the `VirtualFileProvider`'s Open method the virtual path of `~/plugin/admin` is being passed in when it should be `~/plugin/admin/Index.aspx` as defined in my route above. Have I messed up my routes or am I right to be expecting this to happen?

Comment: That first FileExists call happens before the controller runs, and must return false or IIS will try to serve it as a static files. The request for the actual aspx file comes later, when the controller requests a view.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. You must register your `VirtualPathProvider` within the `Global.asax` `Application_Start` handler.
2. You must call the view in your DLL using the special path like so: `return View("~/Plugin/YOURDLL.dll/FULLNAME_YOUR_VIEW.aspx");`

Here's an article with downloadable code sample that demonstrates this:

http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/

Comment: what is Plugin folder ? or is it just a namespace?

Comment: There is such a thing as the Internet Archive, and it has this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20150414200605/http://wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins

Answer (score 4):

The built-in WebFormsViewEngine uses VirtualPathProviders, so if you write a VPP and register it, you won't need to make any changes to the view engine.