# Including Views in a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340183/plug-in-architecture-for-asp-net-mvc) I found out how to create a plugin architecture for MVC. I'm not the whole way down that path yet but I do have a nice way of splitting things up.

One thing that is bugging me though is the intellesense for the View when they are in the Class Library. Developing them in the core MVC project and then copying them across is a pain.

Basically the problem that I'm having is that I don't understand well enough how Visual Studio is dealing with the aspx files. I'm on Beta at the moment, I'm thinking that I might be able to take advantage of explicit view building that comes with RC1.

Any help would be appreciated.

update:

I have all of the finding of views sorted out when it is actually running, its the editing of them in visual studio I'm interested in. Do they have to be in a web type project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The views can be whereever you like. There's a ViewLocator and you can replace it and put them wherever you like: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/31/37827/.

You could put them in a binary or in a database if it made you happy.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've got them working from resources with a ViewLocator. Its more trying to get VS to do its usual intellesense stuff. They are in a code library at the moment.

Comment: In the end I changed the way that I was doing and moved towards using areas of functionality. Borrowing heavily from Phil's example.