# How to control assembly name of MVC3 views?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, assemblies, view

How can I make my views in my MVC3 Web project be compiled into my project assembly as defined in the project properties? E.g. I don't want them to be generated to a dynamic/random assembly.

The reason for this is that the views reference `internal` classes in a referenced library, therefore, the referenced library needs to include the MVC3 project's assembly in its assembly info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bit more complicated than one would hope but is possible (at least for compiling into another dll outside of the main assembly)
See:

http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/

[Including Views in a Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531416/including-views-in-a-class-library)

Comment: Thanks, via that link I found the Razor Single File Generator VS extension from Microsoft which is what I'm trying to use now. It's not actually working (`Custom tool error: Could not load generator "MvcView"`) but I'll post another question about that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally tried this but would adding:

```
<PropertyGroup>    
    <EnableUpdateable>false</EnableUpdateable>    
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to the project file have the desired effect?

Comment: Actually that didn't do it. But I do like the option to compile the views ate compile time, I'll leave that in there. The views still go to a random assembly.