# MS Entity Framework 4.1 - Maintain data across restructuring

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using the Code First approach to manage the EF. However all the examples I have seen don't seem to allow you to use EF where you are able to make changes to the DB schema and preserve your data.

So say I have an entity/object of:

```
public class Person
   int Id;
   string NickName;
```

and I now add Age so:

```
public class Person
   int Id;
   string NickName; 
   int Age;
```

how can I preserve the data that may already be in the database for "Person"?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720363/entity-framework-4-1-custom-database-initializer-strategy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4.1 - Tracking and manually deploying DDL changes using T-SQL.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753064/entity-framework-4-1-tracking-and-manually-deploying-ddl-changes-using-t-sql)

Answer (score -1):

Dont call the System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer().

Or call System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer() with CreateDatabaseIfNotExists().

Calling with DropCreateDatabaseAlways or DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges will always drop Db.

Comment: I dont agree. I have given TheEdge some options. Sure I could have added one more (ie implement IDatabaseInitializer urself) but the above answers the question.

Comment: hes asking for a solution and you are answering with bunch of `Don't`s. The `Do`s part is missing in your answer :)