# Pulling a View from a database rather than a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to load a view from a database rather than from a file on disk? It doesn't necessarily have to be a database, could be any string really.

I think I asked this question too soon...I still look forward to any answers but I will definitely do some more research first.

### Edit

So I wrote a quick sample that does what I want - to a point. I'll post updates as I get everything working properly.

```
public class DbPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider {
    public DbPathProvider() : base() {

    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath) {
        if (virtualPath.StartsWith("/test") || virtualPath.StartsWith("~/test"))
            return true;

        return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
        //deal with this later
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) {
        if (virtualPath.StartsWith("/test") || virtualPath.StartsWith("~/test"))
            return new DbVirtualFile(virtualPath);

        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        //deal with this later
    }

    public class DbVirtualFile : System.Web.Hosting.VirtualFile {

        public DbVirtualFile(string path) : base (path) {
            //deal with this later
        }

        public override System.IO.Stream Open() {
            return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("this is a test"));
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

After playing around with it I found something interesting. If I remove the `return base...` from the `FileExists()` and `GetFile()` methods and only return true & my `DbVirtualFile` the returned file is parsed and output is as expected. (Such as if I put `<%:DateTime.Now.ToString()%>`) - however it doesn't when I add the tests and the base returns it just outputs a literal string of whatever is in my DbVirtualFile (god I hope this makes sense) - any thoughts out there?

### Final

It works. I just didn't add the inherits to the page I was testing. In this case: `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>`

Hope this helps someone else out there trying to do the same thing.

Comment: You need to inherit from something other than VirtualFile, I'm looking for the correct class.

Comment: I got it working. I forgot to add `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>` to the Virtual File...too early in the morning!

Comment: Your model is a dynamic?

Comment: No, it's just a test...wanted to see if this was possible :) I just copied it from a pre-generated cshtml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to create some new providers though. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236972/using-virtualpathprovider-to-load-asp-net-mvc-views-from-dlls) is a question that does basically the same thing, except from embedded files. [This](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views) is an example that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Heh, Thanks. I was just doing some reading on implementing my own View providers.

Comment: @Morder: I had the exact code to do this, unfortunately I left it at my previous company.

Comment: foolish of you. When I left my last place I accidentally backed up all the source code onto a dvd then i accidentally dropped it into my bag. Then I accidentally refer to it now and then

Comment: @BritishDeveloper: Sometimes there are a lot of directories, and your backups just aren't complete.