# ASP.NET MVC load Razor view from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

ScottGu mentioned that we should be able to [load a Razor view from a database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) (check the comments section), so does anybody have an example on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

You might want to check [Pulling a View from a database rather than a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367106/pulling-a-view-from-a-database-rather-than-a-file) or [Using VirtualPathProvider to load ASP.NET MVC views from DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236972/using-virtualpathprovider-to-load-asp-net-mvc-views-from-dlls)

Taking the code from my previous question on the subject.

In your `FileExists()` method on the other page you replace the test code I have there with some db code that actually checks to see if the virtualPath has an entry in your database. Your database would look something like:

```
Views --tablename
    Path --view's virtual path
    SomeOtherValue
```

...and your call would then be something like

```
public class DbPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider {
    public DbPathProvider() : base() {

    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath) {
        Database db = new Database();
        return db.Views.Any(w => w.Path == virtualPath);
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) {
        return new DbVirtualFile(virtualPath);
    }
}
```

And now we modify the DbVirtualFile

```
public class DbVirtualFile : System.Web.Hosting.VirtualFile {

    public DbVirtualFile(string path) : base (path) {

    }

    public override System.IO.Stream Open() {
        Database db = new Database();
        return new System.IO.MemoryStream(
                   db.Views.Single(v => v.Path == this.VirtualPath));
    }
}
```

The virtualPath doesn't have to correspond to a real filesystem if you don't want it to. You can override the functionality by implementing these two classes.

You can then register your new VirtualPathProvider in the global.asax like so

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new DbPathProvider());
```

I hope this better answers your question.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in the tutorial the solution points to (http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views) the condition is to have an actual file on disk (/View/Pages/Test.aspx) and just supply the "filling." I'm looking for a solution that allows me to specify the entire page.

Comment: Updated question based on confusion as to the virtual paths

Comment: I'm working with an example right now that doesn't use a database. In FileExists I check for "/View/Home/Test.cshtml" (my virtual file) and in the Open method I return new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<h1>Hi</h1>")); When I do this I get "Directory '[..]\View\Home' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes." Any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post your code in your question - the simplest way to test is to forcibly return true in the `FileExists` method - also did you register your VirtualPathProvider?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist on disk you need to implement the directory components of the VirtualPathProvider - when I set up something similar I found that the system was actually working from a list of all available views loaded on the first request rather than just calling FileExists on each request.

Comment: @pbz override GetCacheDependency in your vpp returning null where the view is from your db