# Strange behaviour when loading razor view from custom VirtualPathProvider (ASHX Source)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, virtualpathprovider, viewbag, cache-dependency

I get some strange behaviour when I load data via my custom VirtualPathProvider.
It might be important to mention, that I am trying to use this view as a layout.

```
public class MyVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
    public MyVirtualPathProvider()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart) 
    {
        if ((virtualPath.StartsWith("/Path/") ||
            virtualPath.StartsWith("~/Path/")) && virtualPath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
        {
            String name = virtualPath.Replace("/Path/", "").Replace(".cshtml", "");
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/Handler.ashx?path=" + name);
            return new WebCacheDependency(uri.ToString());
        }

        return base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        if ((virtualPath.StartsWith("/Path/") || 
            virtualPath.StartsWith("~/Path/")) && virtualPath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
            return true;

        return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (virtualPath.StartsWith("/Path/") || virtualPath.StartsWith("~/Path/"))
            return new TemplateVirtualFile(virtualPath);

        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }
}
```

I also have implemented a custom (dummy) CacheDependency

```
public class WebCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    public WebCacheDependency(String url)
    {
        this.SetUtcLastModified(DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
}
```

Now there are two things that don't work. First, all loaded views are being cached and secondly, code inside the file (@Html.ActionLink ... etc.) does not work, It just gives an error "assembly missing".

Has anyone an idea how to remedy those two problems?

There's already a solution of the second problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159314/load-razor-view-from-db-but-viewbag-is-broken)) however I really don't get it how this problem can be solved inside the FileExists method.

Thank you!

Update: An image of the error message
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your web.config properly setup for Razor?  If you don't specify the **pageBaseType** of `WebViewPage` you won't have access to the `ViewBag` as its not in the default base type, `WebPageBase`.

Your web.config should look something like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    [...]
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Note the **pageBaseType** attribute.  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.razor.configuration.razorpagessection.pagebasetype(v=vs.99).aspx

> By default, the default value for **PageBaseType** is [System.Web.WebPages.WebPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpage%28v=vs.99%29.aspx).