# ASP.NET MVC4 @MvcHtmlString.Create() issues with @Html.RenderPartial()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to dynamically render pages from database. The view looks like this

```
@model MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;
    Layout = Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PageInnerLayout.cshtml";
}

@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Content)
```

MyModel has just 3 properties; `Id, Title and Content`

If the `Content` has just HTML, the view renders just fine. But in some cases, I need to render partials too. So `Content` may contain code like

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_FooterPartial");
}
```

This does not work. Its being rendered literally, like shown in the image below

[image: Example of rendered page]

How do I fix this so that the page is rendered properly?

Comment: you can add flag for example `IsPartialContent` to model, and if it is true then render partial manualy, also you can see on [razorgenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Grundy I didn't quite understand your answer. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought that the content can only be html or a line `renderpartial` with no other html code

Comment: i think template for [razorengine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) what you need

Comment: `@MvcHtmlString.Create` put string in output as is, so if you want put not only html you must process your `Model.Content` for example in razor engine, and output result string

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the difference between `Html.RenderPartial` and `Html.Partial` helper methods. `RenderPartial` directly write the result to `HttpContext.Response` while `Partial` return it as a `MvcHtmlString`. You need to replace the `RenderPartial` with `Partial` and maybe the `RenderAction` with `Action`.

**Edited:**

You need to render the content if contains the razor view scripts. If so it means you are actually storing the `views` or `partial views` inside the database. You can create a new `VirtualPathProvider` to help loading the views from the database. For more information see [ASP.NET MVC load the Razor views from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218454/asp-net-mvc-load-razor-view-from-database) and [ASP.NET MVC and virtual view](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views)

Comment: @Vivek You need to render the content of `Model.Content` as a view if it contains the razor view scripts, inside the controller's action before pass it to view.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. I implemented a `VirtualPathProvider` and it still wouldn't render Razor Code

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this with VirtualPathProvider, but it didn't work.

Finally what I did was to write the Content from database into a temporary view and then render the view. It worked

```
public ActionResult DynamicPage(int id) {
  var dynamicPage = new PagesContext().Pages.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);

  string webroot = Server.MapPath("~").TrimEnd('\\');
  string fileName = webroot + "\\Views\\\\Solutions\\Temp.cshtml";

  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, dynamicPage.Content);
  return View("Temp");
}
```

Here, the Content property of the dynamicPage containts HTML(including Razor code)

Comment: I beg to disagree, this solution has performance issue and it is not thread safe also. The multiple requests executing in the multiple threads try to write to a single file leads to the synchronization issues.

Comment: @KambizShahim Yes. That is an issue. Any suggestions please?