# How to Render content include razor syntax in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: razor

In my database there is a record which include some razor syntax like that "Hello @Model.Name, Wellcome ..." When I get this record to the view how can I render this model property ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.

1. [Pulling a View from a database rather than a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367106/pulling-a-view-from-a-database-rather-than-a-file)
2. http://razorengine.codeplex.com
3. http://ibashir.blogspot.com/2010/11/razor-parser-without-mvc.html
4. http://blog.andrewnurse.net/2010/07/22/UsingTheRazorParserOutsideOfASPNet.aspx

I'm biased towards the RazorEngine from codeplex it's been used in the Mini-Profiler from the developers of this very site.