# ASP.net MVC: Execute Razor from DB String?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I was thinking about giving end users the ability to drop Partial Views (controls) into the information being stored in the database. Is there a way to execute a string I get from the database as part of the Razor view?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Are you trying to store string "@Html.RenderPartial(\"SomeView.cshtml\")" in db, then get Razor engine to execute that in your template?

Comment: Daryl, that is exactly what I am talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update (I forgot all about this)

I had asked this question previously (which lead me to create RazorEngine) [Pulling a View from a database rather than a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367106/pulling-a-view-from-a-database-rather-than-a-file)

I know of at least two: [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer)

I have a bias towards RazorEngine as it's one that I've worked on but I have a much simpler one at Github called [RazorSharp](https://github.com/Buildstarted/RazorSharp) (though it only supports c#)

These are all pretty easy to use.

#### RazorEngine:

```
string result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(razorTemplate, new { Name = "World" });
```

#### MvcMailer

I haven't used this one so I can't help.

#### RazorSharp

RazorSharp also supports master pages.

```
string result = RazorSharp.Razor.Parse(new { Name = "World" }, 
                                       razorTemplate, 
                                       masterTemplate); //master template not required
```

Neither RazorSharp, nor RazorEngine support any of the Mvc helpers such as `Html` and `Url`. Since these libraries are supposed to exist outside of Mvc and thus require more work to get them to work with those helpers. I can't say anything about MvcMailer but I suspect the situation is the same.

Hope these help.

Comment: This is not able to parse if the content has got some special characters in javascript code? like var x = '(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?';

Comment: @Rahatur just like in cshtml you'll probably have to escape with two `@@` but it's been so long I'm just guessing here.

Comment: That might be the issue! Will give that a try.