# ASP.NET MVC3 link with image inside @Html.Raw

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Good day, I'm try to use action links with `Url.Action` inside `@Html.Raw` in my ASP.NET MVC3 project. Everything works fine without `@Html.Raw`, but with it images can't display on the page, I'm try to use `Html.Encode` inside Raw, but then it's show me the naked HTML on the page.

```
@Html.Raw(<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1})" target="_blank">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/simpleImage.png")"/>
            </a>)
```

Any ideas why it's not render right code?Also when I hover over the place with image it pop up for me next code: `sitename.com/Controller/@Url.Action(`

I'm try to shielding the " it's not help

**Edit**

This action link is a part of query from database, which I display like next:

```
@Html.Raw(model.FieldWithHtmlCharactersInDatabase)
```

Comment: if `Everything works fine without @Html.Raw,` then why are you using it?

Comment: because I'm add this info to database, and need to display it on the page

Comment: Where does this `@Html.Display` relate to `@Html.Raw`?

Comment: You are using very bad design of storing markup in the database, I will strongly recommend you to refactor your strategy of storing image and anchor link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass string, try this

```
@Html.Raw("<a href='" + @Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1})' " + target='_blank'>
                <img src='" + @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/simpleImage.png") " + "/>
            </a>")
```

Comment: @Rakstit This works perfectly fine. Please post the exact code you are using rather than mention one thing but then comment about something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead where you are passing in the string variable and escaping the `"` correctly.

```
@Html.Raw("<a href=\"" + 
    Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1}) 
    + "\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"" + 
    Url.Content("~/Content/Images/simpleImage.png") + "\"/></a>")
```

However I do not understand why you want this in `@Html.Raw` when this will give you the same output;

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1})" target="_blank">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/simpleImage.png")" />
</a>
```

**Update**

After you have updated your question, you are attempting to Execute Razor code from DB strings. I would suggest that you take a look at some of these questions on StackOverFlow;

[ASP.net MVC: Execute Razor from DB String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523918/asp-net-mvc-execute-razor-from-db-string)

[Pulling a View from a database rather than a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367106/pulling-a-view-from-a-database-rather-than-a-file)

Please note that your original question is very different from what you want.

Comment: Because it's a part of string from my database which I display on the page inside @Html.Raw(model.SomeValue)

Comment: Where is this mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Rakstit This works perfectly fine. Please post the exact code you are using rather than mention one thing but then comment about something else.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1, width=100, height=100})" alt="" />
```

will yield this output:

```
<img src="Controller/ActionName/1?width=100&amp;height=100" alt="" />
```

You will get the same surrounding Action helper with Raw:

```
<img src="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1, width=100, height=100}))" alt="" />
```

So this must be a bug in Razor/MVC. One (tedious and ugly) workaround I found is this:

```
@Html.Raw("<img src=\"" + Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {id = 1, width=100, height=100}) + "\" alt=\"\" />" )
```

Hopefully Microsoft will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem in the future, for me it worked to remove the ~ infront of the image string!

Comment: I think you would do better to open your own topic by explaining your problem in more detail. You will have a better chance of getting help.

Comment: @EnzoBLANCHON I dont have the Problem anymore it's just a fix for the problem above, if somebody has the same problem again.