# Show HyperLink in HTML.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, hyperlink

I am using HTML.Raw in a few detail views that I have - so that the text output shows with any carriage returns or spaces.  However, sometimes someone may type in a Web Address in the middle of text. I have no idea where the Web Address will be in the text.  How can I get it so that the Web Address will show as a hyperlink?

The only things I can find in a search is where the coder knows the position of the Web Address.  Here is an example (plus it is very old). [ASP.NET MVC3 link with image inside @Html.Raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439407/asp-net-mvc3-link-with-image-inside-html-raw)

FYI, this is a help desk system for people to open tickets for their problems.  Sometimes they may put in that they cannot access http://nameofwebsite.com or something similar.

Here is my code:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Note.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `@Html.Raw(Model.Note.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))` You can just style the element - `<div style="whitespace: pre;">@Model.Note</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression when filling your model or even as a helper in the view to 'linkify' hyperlinks.

Here's an example of the regex (shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758140/2075402)):

```
var html = Regex.Replace(html, @"^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+" +
                     "\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?" +
                     "([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$",
                     "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

This will then render using `Html.Raw()` as a hyperlink.