# Render html and razor syntax inside Html.Raw

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to render razor syntax inside `Html.Raw` in razor page of mvc. A example is provided bellow. Anyone can tell me is it possible? My goal is rander html text as row html in browser also with some razor syntax like bellow. How is that possible?

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.PageContent); //ViewBag.PageContent contains html+ razor syntax as string text
```

Above Html.Raw only render the html in browser but razor syntax display as plain text like `<title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>`

Any idea?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523918/asp-net-mvc-execute-razor-from-db-string).

Comment: No. I have checked your suggested link answer but there is no any working answer.

Comment: It is enough to point you in the right direction.  Unless you are looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you by using + seperators between the HTML and Razor Syntax.. In this example I have a "RazorPage.cshtml" file that relies on a corresponding "RazorPage.cshtml.cs" file (not shown because it's irrelevant). This example "injects" dynamic data into the title tag and the p tag.

```
@page
@model ProjectName.Pages.RazorPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RazorPageTitle";
    ViewBag.PageContent = "<title>" + @ViewData["Title"] + "</title>" + "<p>View Source Shows the " + @ViewData["Title"]  + " Tag</p>";
}

<h1>RazorPage</h1>

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.PageContent)
```