# MVC3 Custom VirtualPathProvider not rendering Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've tried to copy this [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367106/pulling-a-view-from-a-database-rather-than-a-file/13668845#13668845).

The only change I've made is changing the text that it'll output :

```
public override System.IO.Stream Open() 
{
    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage\r\n@{ViewBag.Title = \"About Us\";}\r\n"));
}
```

But I can't seem to persuade it to evaluate the Razor mark-up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, Exactly this but with the data in a database seems to work :I think it may have something to do with my manually inserted carriage returns ... Oh well

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF8 encoding instead of ASCII

Comment: Yeah - They're all ascii characters, but I did get desperate enough to try that anyway ... it's the same :)