# EditorTemplates in a class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET-MVC2 project, I have built some user controls that resides in Views\Shared\EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates folders.

I am trying to pull this templates into a class library, in order to make them reusable, how do I do that!

I don't know if this might help but a little more details; some of the templates are named after types like (string, Int32, etc) and some are named like RemoteCombo, and specified with a template hint in UIHint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VirtualPathProvider to load ASP.NET MVC views from DLLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236972/using-virtualpathprovider-to-load-asp-net-mvc-views-from-dlls)

Comment: Brad Wilson says: "In the box, XCOPY is the best option. There are third party libraries that can do things like embed views for redistribution (like MvcTurbine)." so if you want the controls embedded there are 3rd party options, I'd settle for xcopy tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just create a library and put ascx files there. You will have to create a 'code-only' version of your templates that renders appropriate html.

Microsoft had to do just that in order to deliver default templates inside System.Web.Mvc.dll

More information about templates can be found on **[this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html)** blog - it's a nice series of posts about templating in MVC. (take a look at 'Built-In Display Templates' section)

This is a default Editor Template for Decimals (from System.Web.Mvc.dll)

```
internal static string DecimalTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
    if (html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model)
    {
        html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0.00}", new object[] { html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model });
    }
    return StringTemplate(html);
}
```

All default templates can be seen in Reflector in `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

Comment: what do you mean by "code-only" templates? Do you mean Html helpers, or something else that is called with the right templateHint in EditorFor<>()?

Comment: @jfar - could you please give a code sample of how the embedded resource can be used by MVC framework to render a template for a model?

Comment: @Jakub Konecki, I've added a "dupe" link that shows how to do this.

Comment: @Jakub Konecki - in this DecimalTemplate scenario, when I provide my own implementation of the DecimalTemplate, is it always going to instantiate my own DecimalTemplate, and how does it know, do I have to register it somewhere?

Comment: I would rather go with the code-only templates over the recommend solution (VirtualPathProvider)in the duplicate link.