# ViewBag and Models are not avaialable when tried Pluggable MVC areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas, pluggable

I have tried the pluggable structure as discussed in this post: 
[Pluggable MVC view return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032239/pluggable-mvc-view-return-null)

It is also explained in this post: http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/

When I try to access ViewBag/Model in one of the area, it gives me this error:

---

- The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'model' does not exist in the current context***

Comment: If you want a hassle free plugin system read my blog article: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are serving the view from an unknown location there's no longer the ~/Views/web.config that applies to it. And as you know inside this file is specified the base type for Razor views (`System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`). So one possibility is to add an `@inherits` directive to the top of your view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@model MyViewModel

<div>@ViewBag.FooBar</div>
```

Side-note: since you already have a view model why even care about `ViewBag`? Why not get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Darin. It did not help in fact. I must be doing something crazy. This is just a proof of concept to make some basis to port my project from composite web application blocks to areas. So I need to cover both viewbag and models.

Comment: Well, this has always worked for me. I am afraid that without showing your code and an example that would allow us to reproduce the problem you are having it's close to impossible to help you further.