# Asp.net MVC ViewEngineResult + embeded views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a working function that returns me a processed view (or partial view)

I call this function sending the virtual path to the view, like:

```
string viewHtml = GetViewPageHtml(this, model, "~/Views/PartialView.cshtml");

public static string GetViewPageHtml(Controller controller, object model, string viewName)
{
    ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);

    if (result.View == null)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("View Page {0} was not found", viewName));

    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter output = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, result.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, output);
            result.View.Render(viewContext, output);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Is there any solution of making this function to find embedded views?

If i have an embedded view and call the same function, it doesn't finds the page:

```
// not working
string viewHtml = GetViewPageHtml(this, model, "Application1.Views.EmbededPartialView.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve such solutin:

1. Instead of views in resources, consider RazorGenerator, which compiles views into code, and have ViewEngine
2. Second way is to use `VirtualPAthProvider` - more about this you can find here: [Using VirtualPathProvider to load ASP.NET MVC views from DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236972/using-virtualpathprovider-to-load-asp-net-mvc-views-from-dlls)