# ASP.net MVC views in class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modularization

I'm developing a framework application, and I want individual implementations to have the possibility to add new functionality simply. For controllers this is easy, just compile it and drop it in the bin directory, but what about views? Is it possible to embed a view as a resource in a class library or something? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: Following that post made me find this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx

Comment: A link belongs in a comment, not as an answer.