# Use view from other MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I have a few MVC3 projects that uses the same partial views. These views contain parts of forms that i can easily reuse in other MVC projects. is there a way to centralize `Views`. Like, in another project perhaps? So i can add the assembly of the project and easily call the views i need?

Otherwise i have to copy the reusable views folder every time i start a new project. And when i make a change to one of those views, then i have to change it in all the other projects too. Would be better if i could put it in one place and reference to it somehow.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make ASP.NET MVC 3 use views (aspx, ascx) files from an external assembly in my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823579/how-can-i-make-asp-net-mvc-3-use-views-aspx-ascx-files-from-an-external-assem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to simply map a shared virtual folder in your views folder, using IIS's virtual folder feature.  That way all apps that use the same views will actually point to the same physical folder.

You may have some challenges with deployment, and you could make the shared folders part of their own project.  But you will need to deal with that both on the local dev machine and the server.