# Add a custom ViewLocator to a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in asp.net MVC, this is my situation.
I have a controller called CustomerController.
I created a subfolder to my Views/Customer folder.
I want to manage views in this subfolder from my controller.

I think the right solution is the answer from Dale Ragan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc).

But I don't have a ControllerFactory, I want to add the custom ViewLocator to my CustomerController if possible.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

the solution from [weelink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc#1514764) would work, juste add it to the `Application_Start`

Comment: It seems like that solution is applied to all controllers. I would use the Dale Ragan solution, just on a single controller if possible.