# Develop an application Module wise in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to develop an application in asp.net module wise In which we can add new module and remove existing module dynamically? Or
Suppose we create an asp.net web application. how to convert that application in an module so that the application will work as a module of another application.

Comment: In your question 'module' seems to be a buzz word. :) But could you further clarify your question?

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Sandeep G B are you sure is a duplicate of views in different assemblies?.......

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer, since the question is not descreptive enough I thought Narinder Saggar is referring to separating out web application into different assemblies and loading the same at run time. Narrinder Saggar should provide more details for us to understand if it is a duplicate or a different question all together.

Comment: No, he's talking about separating an application in modules. A component-based application! :) It's descriptive enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is fairly open-ended as a "module" can be defined in many ways.  I will mention three ways to solve this scenario.  Before you jump to using WCSF, please verify that #1 and #2 don't meet your needs.

---

**#1 [WEB PARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk23dydw.aspx)**

Depending on if you want composite applications or simply just the ability to have features enabled or disabled for a user, a web part may be your answer.  I have used web parts with success in the past and based on your needs it may work.

**#2 [Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972970.aspx)**

This is straightfoward- you can simply refactor existing elements that you want shared across applications into server controls.  Our team does this for many of our UI elements such as grids and user management pages.  Depending on how you want modules, this may work too.

and finally...

**#3 [Web Client Software Factory](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20Client%20Software%20Factory&referringTitle=Home)**

> The Web Client Software Factory (WCSF)
>   provides a set of guidance for
>   architects and developers building
>   enterprise Web applications. The
>   factory includes samples, reusable
>   code and a guidance package which
>   automates key development tasks from
>   within Visual Studio.
>
> Using the Web Client Software Factory
>   assets, developers can create
>   Composite Web applications composed of
>   independently developed and deployed
>   modules. These modules are dynamically
>   brought together at runtime into a
>   common shell. Additionally the factory
>   includes support for ASP.NET AJAX thus
>   providing users with a richer and more
>   responsive user experience.

Comment: Only #3 relates to the question. I almost downvoted you. I suggest you re-read the question, then edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Based on the way the question was asked, I wanted to give some background on how to find a simple solution.  Often when a developer sets out to begin working on a project, they make it more complicated than it needs to be.  WCSF is the answer and I clearly said "Before you jump to using WCSF."  The answer is there, the background is there.  It is how I like to have answers presented to me when there is a high level of complexity potentially.