# easiest way to change path of Views for a certain controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Controller called BaseController and Controller1 and Controller2 inherit from it.

All of the views for these controllers are under ~/Views/Base/  the reason for this is that Controller1 and 2 do the exact same thing but have custom attributes for certain things on some overriden actions.

I want to be able to point to ~/Views/Base as the location to look for views in both Controller1 and Controller2.  Now can i do this without having to implement my own ViewLocator as per Dale's solution in this post [Views in separate assemblies in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc)

I would prefer to not throw all these views into ~/Views/Shared as they aren't really shared except in between these two Controllers.

Comment: Looks like the Dale's solution I liked to is deprecated.  ViewLocator seems to be gone from MVC2/3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom view engine in order to add this new location in the search list:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine // WebFormViewEngine - if you are using WebForms
{
    public MyViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats.Union(new[] 
        {
            "~/Views/Base/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Base/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Base/{0}.aspx",
            "~/Views/Base/{0}.ascx",
        }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
```

Comment: thanks.  but will this mean all controllers/views will use this?  Would that have any negative impact on performance.  Would prefer if this didn't change my entire application's view engine like this.

Comment: @sylon, yes indeed, all controllers will look into this location. It won't have negative impact on performance as when running in Release mode view locations are cached by the framework.

Comment: I guess I will settle for this but it would be nicer if this could be specific to the controller though, if you know what I mean.  Just for the sake of tidiness.