# Use view from another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have project with views and project with controller, which must use view from first project.
I found some solutions like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc), but problem is that first project already include reference on second project with controller.