# Two ASP MVC view projects in the same solution, [Views in multiple projects]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was wondering how to route view across projects, assuming it was possible to have views in separate projects... is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to pass entire view from one project to another even if it is in same solution.
You should find alternative solution like using WCF(you would be able to pass the data, view can be rendered from the other project) or try using areas instead of different projects.
This is not the solution but this might help.
:)