# Rendering Views from external assemblies in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm able to load controllers from external assemblies in MVC6, due to how it finds controllers. But I am unable to render a view that is also in that assembly, as it says it can not be found. The assembly that contains the views and controllers looks as so:
[image]

The project it's imported into finds the controller find, and executes the code inside it fine, but then fails finding the view, showing this error
[image]

Comment: what kind of error you get when you hit the controller action which is supposed to return the view?

Comment: I have updated my question with the error it returns

Comment: possible duplicate of [Views in separate assemblies in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load views from a separate assembly, you need `EmbeddedFileProvider` and `CompositeFileProvider`.  I provide more information on how to use these here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34366119/188740

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the error, you will see that it tries to find the views under `Views` directory which is relative to application path. However, you views live under `Mvc/Views` path.

You can try to override this. I am not sure what is the easiest and proper way to do this but the first think that comes to my mind is that you can provide a FileProvider [here on `RazorViewEngineOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/b2318bc4713f03cba3fb626abc35bb105c16475f/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngineOptions.cs) which sees `/Mvc` as the root folder. [Here is an example](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/b2318bc4713f03cba3fb626abc35bb105c16475f/samples/MvcSample.Web/Startup.cs#L65-L70) on how you can configure this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this in, what I believe to be, an incredibly hacky way.

Since the views are in each project, inside the `src` folder, I changed the RazorViewEngine root from the Mvc application, in the `src\Branch.Web`, to just `src`. So every view has to be prefixed with the Project name, such as `Branch.Game.Halo4`. To enable this I just execute this code in the `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`

```
    services.AddMvc().ConfigureRazorViewEngine(options =>
    {
        var oldRoot = ApplicationEnviroment.ApplicationBasePath;
        var trimmedRoot = oldRoot.Remove(oldRoot.LastIndexOf('\\'));

        options.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(trimmedRoot);
    });
```

It isn't perfect, but it works.