# How to use one partial view in Two MVC Project for same solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two mvc projects in the same solution. The parent project Name is WebAPP and the child project name is SocialMedia.

In the SocialMedia project I have a partial view named 
"_partialSocialMedia.cshtml". 
I am using it easily in the SocialMedia project, as follows:

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_partialSocialMedia.cshtml");
 }
```

I want to use the same partial view into the parent project without re-creating it. I have tried to use it like this:

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/SocialMedia/Views/Shared/_partialSocialMedia.cshtml");
 }
```

But it is giving me an error as the view is not found in the specific path. 
I have tried a lot of tricks using different path specifications.

Please note: I have already added the SocialMedia project as a reference into WebApp (the parent project) and the partial view exist in the following folder:  `SocialMedia>Views>Shared>_partialSocialMedia.cshtml`.

Comment: `PartialView` can be only accessed to the scope of that Project. you can consider maintaining two `Areas` in the same project, so you can share the `PartialView` across `Areas`.

Comment: [This SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746/views-in-separate-assemblies-in-asp-net-mvc) should help you.